# Trigonometry and Complex Numbers with Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation

> The number
>   $$\text{cis}75^\circ + \text{cis}83^\circ + \text{cis}91^\circ + \dots + \text{cis}147^\circ$$ is expressed in the form $r \, \text{cis } \theta,$ where $0 \le \theta < 360^\circ$. Find a value of $\theta$ in degrees.

I have no idea on how to deal with sequences in any way shape or form, so I am totally lost on this problem! Please help!

Comment: what is $\mathrm{cis}$?

Comment: @gt6989b I think $cis \theta= \cos \theta +i\sin \theta$

Comment: Just to be clear, is the progression of the form $\sum_{k=0}^9\text{cis}(75+8k)$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos75^{\circ}+\cos83^{\circ}+...+\cos147^{\circ}=$$
$$=\frac{2\sin4^{\circ}\cos75^{\circ}+2\sin4^{\circ}\cos83^{\circ}+...+2\sin4^{\circ}\cos147^{\circ}}{2\sin4^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin79^{\circ}-\sin71^{\circ}+\sin87^{\circ}-\sin79^{\circ}+...+\sin151^{\circ}-\sin143^{\circ}}{2\sin4^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin151^{\circ}-\sin71^{\circ}}{2\sin4^{\circ}}=\frac{\sin40^{\circ}\cos111^{\circ}}{\sin4^{\circ}}.$$
$$\sin75^{\circ}+\sin83^{\circ}+...+\sin147^{\circ}=$$
$$=\frac{2\sin4^{\circ}\sin75^{\circ}+2\sin4^{\circ}\sin83^{\circ}+...+2\sin4^{\circ}\sin147^{\circ}}{2\sin4^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{\cos71^{\circ}-\cos79^{\circ}+\cos79^{\circ}-\cos87^{\circ}+...+\cos143^{\circ}-\cos151^{\circ}}{2\sin4^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{\cos71^{\circ}-\cos151^{\circ}}{2\sin4^{\circ}}=\frac{\sin40^{\circ}\sin111^{\circ}}{\sin4^{\circ}}.$$
Thus, 
$$\text{cis}75^\circ + \text{cis}83^\circ + \text{cis}91^\circ + \dots + \text{cis}147^\circ=\frac{\sin40^{\circ}}{\sin4^{\circ}}\text{cis}111^{\circ}.$$
Id est, $\theta=111^{\circ}$ and we are done!